# INT Datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, int, character

Does the INT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT in MySQL Accepts the character '-' ? I used the data type INT in a column and the data inside has the character '-'. And somehow it didn't accept it. If it's not possible for INT data types, should I use VARCHAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values for an integer in SQL  are:

```
-2147483648 through 2147483647
```

And the byte size is 4 bytes.

Other maximum values:

```
BigInt: -9223372036854775808 through 9223372036854775807 (8 bytes)
SmallInt: -32768 through 32767 (2 bytes)
TinyInt: 0 through 255 (1 byte)
```

**it dosent accept any char or string values like "-"**

**use varchar datatype if u want to insert "-"**

Answer (score 1):

Use `VARCHAR(45)` or `TEXT` datatype, if you want to insert characters.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use **Varchar** DataType for this.

It will support both Int and Special Symbol like '-'

> If you are not going to do any arithmetic operaion means then you can
>   use Varchar or text DataType